# Why didn't Archer go back and help the Illyrians?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

In the episode [Damage](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Damage_(episode)), Archer boards and steals a warp coil from a Illyrian ship. The issue is, it will take the Illyrians 3 years to get home.

After stopping the Xindi, why didn't the Enterprise track down and help the Illyrian ship?

Comment: After stopping the Xindi, the Enterprise was immediately thrown back in time for some more adventure to keep it busy. Nothing says they - or a different ship - didn't go back to help later.

Comment: @OrangeDog - Would have been nice to know they made it back safely.

Comment: @QueenSvetlana - Maybe they did. More likely a passing ship murdered them all for their stuff and pinched the ship.

Comment: Asked elsewhere on the network; https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85954/did-captain-archer-just-forget-the-illyrians-after-leaving-them-stranded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is addressed in the EU novel *[Rise of the Federation: Uncertain Logic](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Uncertain_Logic)*. In brief, Archer made some efforts to find them (by asking a Vulcan ship to scan for them in the general vicinity), but neither hide nor hair of them was ever seen again.

> Reed lowered his gaze, embarrassed at what he’d almost brought up. But
> if anything, Archer was the one who still blamed himself for his act
> of desperation in his darkest days in the Delphic Expanse, when he’d
> stolen a warp coil from an Illyrian science vessel and stranded them
> three years from their homeworld at sublight to ensure that Enterprise
> would reach a vital rendezvous. He’d seen no other choice, and he had
> intended to return the coil if possible—but **circumstances had forced
> Archer to leave the Expanse in haste to defend Earth from the final
> attack of the Xindi hardliners.**
>
> Later, once Archer and Starfleet had persuaded the Vulcan High Command
> to send a follow-up expedition to make diplomatic contact with the
> Xindi, **Archer had requested that the Vulcan crew attempt to locate the
> Illyrian ship and provide aid and recompense if possible. But no sign
> of the vessel had ever been found.** Archer could only hope that they
> had managed to contact a friendly warp-capable vessel and find their
> way home, with the worst damage being to Starfleet’s reputation. But
> he would probably never know for sure.